# Undo move and undo copy not work window explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, window

Able to undo rename and undo delete but undo move and undo copy not work(Press Ctrl + Z or Edit -> undo

This is my step :

- Turn on status bar
- Create a folder and then drag a file into it
- Click Edit(in Menu bar) -> hover to undo (doing this i can see from status bar what I am doing)

--> Both undo move and undo copy are grayed out in the Edit Menu

This is all occurring on my local computer (not over a network).

Also, if I delete a file, it does go to the recycle bin as expected.

Assuming that after the file is copied some process is removing the history, I tried to copy 1 file from folder1 to folder2. Then, without copying again, pasting into folder3. The file copies to both locations fine.

What should I do?

Comment: Hmm. Works as expected for me (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit)

Comment: @Dave I am using local machine not network location. I wonder if any service, feature or config associate or depend on it ?

Comment: @Dave Yes, Of course, I'm just Delete not (Shift + Delete) and i have been go to Recycle bin to confirm

Comment: @Dave If i move or copy both does not appear in Edit Menu(In this case it will be gray out). If i have been rename or delete file before so it will be "Undo Rename" Or "Undo Delete"

Comment: @Dave Sorry to tell you that event is all right. I can copy file1 from folder1 and paste to folder1,2,3...n.

Comment: I can only guess now - I have no idea. I would attempt a system restore, or perform a restore. Maybe a `chkdsk /f`  as well

Comment: @Dave I will try using system restore. Thank you very much for help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I known what is the problem !!!

I had install alternate copier for window explorer and use it as default copier(replace window explorer copy and paste event) like : TeraCopy or ExtremeCopy. 

So if i use those app as default handler both "undo copy and undo move" will not function.